Typescript: Infer inner function param as type of child object keys
I am trying to create wrapper function around react-hook-form's register. I am not able to pass compatible types to register from wrapper function. This question not specific to react-hook-form, but how to enforce inner function param.
I have sample code:

interface Child1 {
    p1: string;
}

interface Child2 {
    p2: number
}

interface Parent {
    child1: Child1;
    child2: Child2
}

function register(o: "child1.p1" | "child2.p2") {return {}}

function getChildRegister(parent: Parent, parentKey: keyof Parent) {
    return function(childKey: keyof Parent[typeof parentKey]) {
        return register(`${parentKey}.${childKey}`)
    }
}

const p: Parent = {child1: {p1: ""}, child2: {p2: 1}}

const result = getChildRegister(p, "child1")("p1") // error! inner function param is not inferred for some reason


I passed child1 to getChildRegister, and expecting inner function param to accept Child1 keys (p1 in this case). But for some reason typescript accepting only string. How to make inner function accept child type keys ?
Typescript Playground Link
Thanks in advance!

You need to make your function generic; typeof doesn't automatically make things generic, you have to do it explicitly.  As shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Thanks. Your solution fixes the problem. It would be great if you can post an anwser with explanation how generic solving the problem even though I don't see point of using generic here.

Your function has the following call signature:
function getChildRegister(
  parent: Parent, parentKey: keyof Parent
): (childKey: never) => {}

The problem is that getChildRegister() is not generic. It does not even attempt to keep track of the particular literal type of parentKey.  Merely writing typeof parentKey doesn't change this; that is equivalent to just keyof Parent.
And then keyof Parent[typeof parentKey] is just keyof (Parent[keyof Parent]), and since Parent[keyof Parent] is the union type {p1: string} | {p2: number}, the keyof operator returns the never type, as there's no key in common to the union members.
If you want the returned function to care about exactly which value was passed in for parentKey, you need the whole thing to be generic, as follows:
function getChildRegister<K extends keyof Parent>(
  parent: Parent, parentKey: K
): (childKey: keyof Parent[K]) => {}

Now parentKey is of generic type K constrained to keyof Parent.  When you call getChildRegister(), the particular value you pass in for parentKey will cause the compiler to infer a literal type for K, and then the returned function will expect keyof Parent[K], which depends on K:
getChildRegister(p, "child1")("p1") // okay
getChildRegister(p, "child1")("p2") // error
getChildRegister(p, "child2")("p1") // error
getChildRegister(p, "child2")("p2") // okay

Looks good.

You can implement the function like this:
function getChildRegister<K extends keyof Parent>(parent: Parent, parentKey: K) {
    return function(childKey: keyof Parent[K]) {
        return register(`${parentKey}.${childKey as any}` as any) 
    }
}

but note that register(`${parentKey}.${childKey}`) isn't going to work by itself anymore because childKey has a more complex relationship to parentKey now, and the compiler can't follow it. In the above I've used a few assertions to the intentionally loose any type to just avoid compiler errors. It's out of scope for this question to investigate how to type things so that the compiler can follow your logic, so I'll leave it there.
Playground link to code
